# selectInput and reactive Plotly bar chart in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard, reactive

I'm just starting out with shiny dashboard and need some help.

Basically I'm trying to build a bar chart (using plotly) in a Shiny Dashboard with a selectInput function, which selects customer data for either May or June.
The structure of the data is:

Experiment <- data.frame(May = c(23,32,34,39,75), June = c(56,23,45,16,76), areas = c("ABD","MAG","DBU","MBSC","PSO"))

Any help understanding how to link the selectInput with the Plotly graph would be much appreciated.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "red", 

      dashboardHeader(

            title = "iReport",
            titleWidth = 500
            ),

      dashboardSidebar(

          # Code assigning items to left-hand menu pane
            sidebarMenu(
              menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "Dashboard", icon = icon("Dashboard")),
              menuItem("Survey", tabName = "Survey", icon = icon("Survey")),
              menuItem("Enquiries", tabName = "Enquiries", icon = icon("Enquiries")),
              menuItem("Metrics", tabName = "Metrics", icon = icon("Metrics")),
              menuItem("Metrics", tabName = "Metrics", icon = icon("Metrics"))
              )),

      dashboardBody(

              tabItems(
                # Tab for Dashboard
                tabItem(tabName = "Dashboard"),
                # Tab for Survey Analytics
                tabItem(tabName = "Survey"),
                #Tab for Enquiry Analytics
                tabItem(tabName = "Enquiries"),
                #Tab for Web Analytics
                tabItem(tabName = "Metrics"),
                #Tab for Twitter Analytics
                tabItem(tabName = "Twitter")
              ),

              # Row 1 objects

              fluidRow(
                # Value boxes
                valueBox(479, "Total No. of Enquiries", color = "red", icon = icon("commenting")),
                valueBox(1.7, "Average response time", color = "red", icon = icon("exchange")),
                valueBox(98, "No. of satisfied customers", color = "red", icon = icon("thumbs-up"))
                      ),

              # Row 2 objects
              fluidRow(
                # Data visualisation 2
                box(width = 6, plotlyOutput("Test2", height = "600px")),
                box(width = 4, selectInput("select", "Select", label = h1("Selection Pane"),choices = list(May = "May", June = "June")))
              )
```

))

```
      server <- function(input, output){    

        #Data
        Experiment <- data.frame(May = c(23,32,34,39,75), June = c(56,23,45,16,76), areas = c("ABD","MAG","DBU","MBSC","PSO"))

        # Plotly bar chart
          output$Test2 <- renderPlotly({

            Test2 <- plot_ly(
              Experiment, x = areas, y = input$select, type = "bar", color = areas)
          })
```

}

```
      shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get()` to convert your variable to something plotly can work with. Also note that you need to do `color = ~areas` instead of `color = areas`, otherwise plotly will try and use the object 'areas', which does not exist. A working example:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output){    

  #Data
  Experiment <- data.frame(May = c(23,32,34,39,75), June = c(56,23,45,16,76), areas = c("ABD","MAG","DBU","MBSC","PSO"))

  # Plotly bar chart
  output$Test2 <- renderPlotly({
    Test2 <- plot_ly(
      Experiment, x = ~areas, y = ~get(input$select), type = "bar", color = ~areas)
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage( 
  plotlyOutput("Test2", height = "600px"),
  selectInput("select", "Select", label = h1("Selection Pane"),choices = list(May = "May", June = "June"))
)
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!
[image]

Comment: Many thanks Florian! This will work a treat - looks awesome :)

Comment: Great, glad I could help!